# NodeMCU, Lua http.get() "Disconnected with error 8" - what is error 8?

Tags: firebase, https, lua, nodemcu

Im trying to use http.get(url, headers, function) to get data from Firebase.

Othersites (also https sites) work fine and i get the response i expect, but firebase gives me a error 8.

I cant find any documentation of this error (or any errors) - does anyone know what it means?

```
http.get("https://<my-firebaseID>.com/somefile.json", "", function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)


NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: b96e31477ca1e207aa1c0cdc334539b1f7d3a7f0
    SSL: true
    modules: adc,bit,cjson,file,gpio,http,i2c,net,node,pwm,spi,struct,tmr,uart,websocket,wifi,wps,tls
 build  built on: 2017-02-23 10:24
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.0.0(656edbf)



HTTP client: Disconnected with error: 8
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP client: Connection timeout
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a correct but still dissatisfactory answer - it's a known issue, see https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1707. If you build a firmware with debug enabled you'll likely see messages similar to the one reported in that issue.

Comment: Allright, thats too bad. Ill try a different approach then.

Comment: Using the net module is just slightly more cumbersome.